# Inserting data to database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to make registration form using PDO.I got next form:

```
<form name="registration" action="registration.php" method="POST">
      <label for 'username'>Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="userName"/>
      <label for 'password'>Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="pass"/>
      <label for 'first_name'>First name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="fullName"/>

      <label for 'email'>Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

And I got registration.php file to connect database and insert values:

```
    <?php


$user = 'root';
$pass = '8169x5it';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass );

$form = $_POST;
$usernName = $form[ 'userName' ];
$pass = $form[ 'pass' ];
$fullName = $form[ 'fullName' ];
$email = $form[ 'email' ];


$sql = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers ( userName, pass, fullName, email ) VALUES ( :userName, :pass, :fullName, :email )";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':userName'=>$userName, ':pass'=>$pass, ':fullName'=>$fullName, ':email'=>$email ) );
?>
```

So, the problem is when I put some in fileds and press Submit button my data NOT insert to database. Please help me, I'm new in PDO and mysql and I can't understand what's wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure PHP actually received your values, then start checking things like the return value of `->execute()`. you're simply assuming the query succeeded, which is exactly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Try setting PDO to throw exceptions if an error occurs. There may be errors silently ignored.

Comment: In order to set PDO's error mode to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION you can use `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass, array(
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => false,
 PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));`

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: Possibly not an issue, but there's a typo - you're setting a variable called `$usernName`, but passing `$userName` to the execute.

Answer (score 0):

- Check for errors
- Remove unnecessary variables
- Check if post variables are set with `isset()`

```
try{
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '8169x5it';
    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass );
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers ( userName, pass, fullName, email ) 
            VALUES ( :userName, :pass, :fullName, :email )";

    if($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
        $query->bindValue(':userName', $_POST['userName']); 
        $query->bindValue(':pass', $_POST['pass']); 
        $query->bindValue(':fullName', $_POST['fullName']); 
        $query->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']); 
        if($query->execute()){
            echo 'execute() success ';
            echo 'affected rows = '.$stmt->rowCount();
        }else{
            echo 'execute() failed';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'prepare() failed';
    }
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Print PDOException message
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```